# Perturbation theory for the homogeneous Fredholm integral equation of the second kind

Tags: reference-request, perturbation-theory

Is there any accessible treatment of perturbation theory for homogeneous Fredholm integrals of the second kind?

Specifically, suppose I have a kernel $K(x,y) = K_0(x,y) + \eta(x,y)$ that is obtained as a additive small perturbation of a kernel $K_0$ with known spectra. Can I exploit this to obtain approximate spectra of $K(x,y)$?

I am a physicist, so ideally I am looking for references with an "applied math style". But whatever you suggest will help.

Comment: Kato, [Perturbation Theory for Linear Operators](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540586616)